# Android Time vs Calendar?

Tags: android, time, calendar

So Android introduced Time in api 3, its an alternative to calendar but why would you use the alternative? What is the pro/cons?

So far:

- Calendar can use DateFormat formating, while Time use another type of formating: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strftime/
- Time is simple while Calendar is somewhat bloated

Anything else to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well because time is easy and performs about as much as calender, I'd go with Time, but if you want more advanced features I'd use calender.